# Create a jquery ui datepicker when a certain key is pressed from within a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm looking to make to make an interactive textarea, where when a user is typing in a textarea, if he types the character "$", a datepicker is created from which he can select a date which will be included inside the textarea afterwards.

Here is a jsfiddle to play around, but I can't seem to making it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/WAzpJ/6/

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple exmaple I've wrote:

```
$('#status_input').keyup(function(){
    txt = $(this);
    if( txt.val().indexOf('$') >= 0 ) {
        $('.datepick').datepicker({
            onSelect: function(theDate) {
                txt.val(txt.val().replace(/\$/, theDate));
                $(this).hide();
            }
        }).show();
    }
});
```

What is basically does is: `onkeyup` checks whether there is `$` characters inside the textarea and if there are - show the datepicker. And when you choose a date - replace the `$` char with the selected date.

hope this will help you.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAzpJ/9/)

Comment: Genius! I would never have thought of that.  Thanks Teneff!

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jquery Hotkeys plugin](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) you can easily do this:

html

```
<textarea id="status_input"></textarea>
```

js

```
$('#status_input').bind('keydown', '$', function(e){
   // dollar sign pressed
   // load datepicker
   $('#status_input').datepicker('show');
})
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  Can you make it work in the jsfiddle?